# How to limit outgoing (SMTP) email service based on SMTP user account in postfix?

Tags: postfix

I have a question, sorry if it's a silly one.

I have postfix on my CentOS and want to provide SMTP access to a few of my customers. But want to limit their email delivery. For example;

Customer A -> 500 emails/month

Customer B -> 1000 emails/month

Is there anyway to do this in Postfix configuration? I searched on Google but couldn't find any useful information.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Policyd](http://www.policyd.org/) has [Quotas](http://www.policyd.org/tiki-index.php?page=Quotas&structure=Documentation)

Ex:

```
  # Limit number of outbound mails per sender per hour to 3,600
  Policy: Default Outbound Policy
  Track: Sender:user@domain
  Period: 2592000

  Type: MessageCount
  CounterLimit: 1000
```